# How to invoke a crashed app automatically in iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, ios

Is it possible to invoke an app automatically when it encounters a crash in iPhone/iPad? If so, any pointers will certainly help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that is possible. If your app crashes, it is terminated - so what could it still do?

Comment: There are times when my app crashes then relaunches itself automatically, though. But I neither added code to do that nor it is an easily replicable situation. :P

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible so design your app NOT to crash instead :)

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this, but there's a reasonable chance you can run code when the app crashes by installing signal handlers in the standard C way for SIGABRT, SIGSEGV, etc.

However I have no idea how you'd make your app relaunch.

As others have said, the best approach is to stop your app crashing - that's what everyone else does.

Comment: Actually, it's what everyone else *tries* to do.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible.